React toastify dynamic notification type issue
I want to remove TS error .
  toast[type](message); // error typescript

I want to make toast notification type dynamic. but it is throwing error typescript
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type
How can I make it dynamic here type is string - calling like this

Maybe you dont need to make it full dynamic you need to add the type coming from the toast library/
